jeep wrangler 1999
went to drive the jeep this morning and it showed the battery was low, check gauges light, squeaky sounds coming from under the hood, and the blinker sounded different. I went home and then tried to start it up again and didn't work and didn't make any unusual sounds. We just changed out the battery and alternator recently, we have a light bar attached, but haven't had any problems with it. What does the problem seem to be?

The squeaky sounds under the hood are very likely from the alternator failing. A squeak is usually a bearing failure, the generator light and electrical issues are classic signs. Even new parts sometimes fail, and unfortunately it sounds like this is the case for you.
